# Ubuntu installation disappeared after a day

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thinkpad

I installed Ubuntu 22 on my new Thinkpad 2 days ago, it ran fine for a day. Then next day when I restarted my laptop, it's showing the ThinkPad boot menu.

[image]

But on the third day, the Ubuntu boot option itself has disappeared. I tried booting from the USB drive, trying to install it again, but it doesn't repair the existing installation and reports low disk space (because the space is taken up by existing Ubuntu)

Is there any other ways of reparing it?

Comment: What did you do inbetween?

Comment: Just setup all the dev tools, worked for like 5-6 hours and then restarted.

Comment: Any advice? Stuck with a laptop which has no hard drive anymore, can't format it can't use it.

Comment: Have you tried starting a live session and mounting the partition?

Comment: I booted the laptop with live usb of Ubuntu, I don't see the hard disk at all either with lsblk or df -h.

Comment: So you're telling the rescue image doesn't detect the disk and the installation image (which isn't that much different) "reports low disk space (because the space is taken up by existing Ubuntu)", meaning it detects the disk? Can you give more details about this low disk space case?

Comment: It reports low disk because it detects the USB storage only, which is only of 8gb capacity. I have finally given the laptop for Lenovo's official service store.